# If $\lambda E-A=\lambda PQ-PBQ$, then $PQ=E$ and $PBQ=A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices with entries $x\in F[\lambda]$, and $P$ and $Q$ be matrices with entries $x\in F$. If $\lambda E-A=\lambda PQ-PBQ$, then $PQ=E$ and $PBQ=A$, where all matrices are of $n$ by $n$, $F$ is a number field and $E$ is the identity matrix? This is consequce in the theory of $\lambda$-matrix, I have no idea about this problem, if $A=B=\lambda E$, I think we can not have $PQ=E$, may someone give me a note? Thanks in advance!

So sorry! where $A$ and $B$ are matrices with entries $x\in F$, and the answer is trivial.

Comment: What's $\lambda$? What if $\lambda$ is in $F$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false for $n=1$, and thus for all $n$.

The matrix $E$ is simply $1$; if you take $A=\lambda$, $P=Q=2$, and $B=\lambda$, then
$$\lambda E-A=\lambda-\lambda = 0 = 4\lambda - 4\lambda = \lambda PQ-PBQ,$$
but $E=1\neq 4=PQ$ and $A=\lambda \neq 4\lambda=PBQ$. These can be extended to matrices of arbitrary dimension by constructing diagonal matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much!